# Atualizar textos da página closed-questions

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, central-de-ajuda

Notei que alguns termos usados na pagina: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions não são os mesmos que aparecem na hora de fechar uma pergunta, por exemplo:

- Na página a palavra `descontextualizada`, mas na hora de fechar esta escrito `fora do escopo`
- No título da página [*closed-questions*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) esta `encerrada`, mas os termos usados no site são `[fechada]` no título e na "dica".
- No título da página [*closed-questions*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) esta `em suspenso`, mas os termos usados no site são `[pendente]` no título e `marcada como pendente` na "dica".

Sei que não é algo que atrapalha, mas muitas pessoas tem dificuldade em assimilar palavras como `escopo` e `descontextualizada` e associa-las.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muito bom achado! Consertei todos os erros e inconsistências que encontrei.

Obrigado!